# Layer navigation Position

Tags: magento-1.9

How to add Layernavigation in **manin content** in my `list.phtml`

```
<reference name="left_first">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
            </block>
        </reference>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple,

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">

            </block>
        </reference>
```

or add this under content reference

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
```

Comment: Ya it's working but it show after products only i want to show first

Comment: use this name="category.products" instead of thsi  after="currency"

Comment: Okay i will check and let you know